# Не запускается скомпилированный файл C++ на macOS из Finder

Tags: c++, консоль, visual-studio-code, sqlite3, macos

**Всем привет !** Я работаю на **MacOS Sonoma 14.4** (MacBook Air **M2**). Использую **Visual Studio Code**. Код написан на **C++** с использованием **"sqlite3.h"**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sqlite3.h"

using namespace std;

// Callback функция для обработки результатов запроса
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    // argc - количество столбцов в результате
    // argv - массив значений полей
    // azColName - массив имен столбцов
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << azColName[i] << ": " << (argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL") << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {


    sqlite3 *DB;
    int check = 0;
    const char* dbPath = "DataBase.db";
    check = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &DB);

    // Проверка на открытие базы
    if (check != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << endl;
        sqlite3_close(DB);
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Base was opened !" << endl;
        cout << "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }


    char *err_message = 0;
    const char *sql_showTable = "SELECT * FROM Books";
    check = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql_showTable, callback, NULL, &err_message);

    // Проверка на успешное выполнение запроса
    if (check != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << endl;
        sqlite3_free(err_message); // Освобождение памяти
        sqlite3_close(DB);
        return -1;
    }


    sqlite3_close(DB);
    return 0;
}
```

> 1: Подключение к базе данных: Программа пытается открыть базу данных
> DataBase.db. Если база данных не может быть открыта (например, из-за
> ошибки доступа или если файл базы данных не существует), программа
> выводит сообщение об ошибке и завершается с ошибкой.
>
> 2: Вывод содержимого таблицы: Если соединение с базой данных успешно
> установлено, программа выполняет SQL-запрос SELECT * FROM Books,
> который выбирает все записи из таблицы Books. Для обработки и вывода
> результатов запроса используется callback-функция callback. Эта
> функция перебирает все строки результатов запроса, выводя значения
> каждого столбца в консоль. Для каждой строки выводятся имена столбцов
> и соответствующие значения полей, причем для пустых полей выводится
> "NULL".
>
> 3: Обработка ошибок: Если при выполнении SQL-запроса происходит ошибка
> (например, если таблицы Books не существует), программа выводит
> сообщение об ошибке, освобождает выделенную память для сообщения об
> ошибке и закрывает соединение с базой данных, после чего завершается с
> ошибкой.
>
> 4: Закрытие соединения с базой данных: После успешного выполнения запроса
> или в случае возникновения ошибки соединение с базой данных
> закрывается.

У меня все файлы находятся сейчас в папке Book_DatabaseNew.
В папке Book_DatabaseNew есть файлы: DataBase.db; main.cpp; main и main.dSYM. Если я запускаю файл через терминал и использую cd - например: открыл терминал, написал cd /Users/dmitry/Documents/Program_Language_Folder/CppProj/Book_DatabaseNew и затем прописываю команду .main, то всё отлично работает. Если я просто перехожу через Finder в папку Book_DatabaseNew и пытаюсь запустить файл main (двойным нажатием), то в терминале выводится:

```
Base was opened !
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

no such table: Books

Saving session...completed.
```

Я даже пытался написать скрипт через automator или через .sh по типу:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
./main
```

upd: через pwd тоже пробовал.
Но даже в этом случае программа не срабатывает. Кстати если запустить скрипт в котором будет прописано что-то по типу такого:

```
FILENAME="example.txt"

echo "Пример текста, который будет записан в файл." > "$FILENAME"

echo "Файл '$FILENAME' был успешно создан и в него был записан текст."
```

..то файл создаётся в каталоге ~ , что опять же странно, ибо скрипт запущен из каталога Book_DatabaseNew. Я не понимаю как это пофиксить ? Я просто хочу запускать файл через ярлык, но это не срабатывает. Я испробовал разные способы, но не нашёл решения. Почему так происходит ? Как в итоге создать рабочий ярлык с программой, которую я могу запустить ? **!! Я буду скачивать эту программу на другой компьютер, по-этому абсолютный путь к бд в самом коде меня не устраивает, хотя это срабатывает !!**
[image: Мой каталог]
[image: Запуск через Finder файла main]

[image: Запуск с использованием cd и ./main]

Как дополнение мой файл tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ сборка активного файла",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lsqlite3"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

И также БД:
[image: БД]

Comment: в `dbPath`  указывайте *абсолютный* путь к файлу.

Comment: Так это не решение проблемы. Если я буду указывать абсолютный путь, то я не смогу на другом компьютере нормально запускать этот файл. Ну, об этом я написал кстати.
Да и с такой логикой я могу использовать терминал для запуска :D

Comment: Принимайте путь в качестве аргумента командной строки, либо через конфиг какой-то.

Comment: Есть способы получить текущий путь откуда запущено приложение. Вот разные способы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799679/programmatically-retrieving-the-absolute-path-of-an-os-x-command-line-app